# Client side pdf javascript plugin, pdfMake support for multiple languages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am looking out for a plugin which can generate the HTML contents in a pdf (should be available for javascript/jQuery/AngularJS). It should have a multi lingual support too.

I have tried the following two, but these plugin have their limitations too:

1. **jsPDF**: Poor support for CSS styles.
2. **pdfMake**: It has support for multiple languages, but one has to specify contents which should be printed in that font. In my case, it is not possible.

> **Specific Issue**: *pdfMake* does allows to style and it has support for languages too, but I have content coming from `ng-model`, where one can type both English and non-English characters. Through pdfMake, the non-English characters are blank, when downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know Javascript the most powerful way is to do it server side with NodeJs. Generating a PDF is quite an expensive thing and you shouldn't give this burden to the user.

If you are able to start a NodeJS server I suggest to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It's a powerful tool to do whatever you want with webpages (also scraping and creating pngs/jpegs from websites).

If you have to bind values inside the html you can do two things:

- Wait for all the angularjs framework to be loaded and then transoform the page into a PDF
- Use a lighter version data-binding tool like [Handlebar](http://handlebarsjs.com/) or [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) to avoid to load the **whole** angular library to print a PDF

Then, if you really want to do it client side you can use something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) that allows you to execute NodeJs-like code inside the browser

I've used this solution in one of my products and it works really really well